# F-Curve Modifier editor not showing

Tags: animation, modifiers, keyframes, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to use an f-curve noise modifier, but it was a bit too harsh for me. I was going to turn it down a bit, but the noise modifier was not showing up in the compositing modifier menu panel. (Sorry if I don't know the actual names of anything.) Barring that, could you at least tell me how to make the noise modifier less extreme?
[image]

.blend file: [http://www.mediafire.com/file/00okkubgycxi0ip/window.blend/file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/3eqrw9qobt27ntc/window.blend/file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, all I had to do was click a little drop down menu in the compositing window and push <kbd>TAB</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Actually, the important point is that you have to select a curve, or its key or its channel in the channel list. But something. Blender works always on a selection basis: you select something, and you do stuff with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too after I deleted the key frames of a curve.
This happen due to two factors:

1. the arrow icon on the window of "only show selected" was activated. Thus deleting the keyframes, there were no curve to show, once clicked it, showed all the curves, but not of my modifier because I deleted the key frames.
2. To sort this, I moved the time line to the beginning, and in the editor on the right hand side, in the physics properties, I animated the strength property of the wind modifier, clicking on the dot on the right hand side (you just can press I on top the input field to insert a key frame) and that inserts a key frame, an making the curve visible again in the graph editor, and also the F-curve, modifiers, and view tabs.